# Magento 2.1.7 and Engintron (nginx) multistore configuration

Tags: multistore, nginx, magento-2.1.7

I cannot find where to enter the environment variables for multiple websites/stores using Engintron - the Magento documentation for nginx shows virtual host config files setting MAGE_RUN_CODE, but this does not seem to work. Does anybody know where these can be set?

Comment: Did you check these [instructions from the DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in my question - I have tried that and it doesn't work. Either I'm doing it wrong or Engintron has a different way of configuring virtual hosts or setting environment variables.

Comment: What is your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engintron uses cPanel virtual hosts, so I followed the Apache multiple website documentation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html) and Engintron did the rest.

Comment: but can not use nginx.conf.sample?